# Inner product that makes vectors an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, orthonormal, positive-definite

Let $X=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a \\
    b 
  \end{pmatrix}
$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix}
    c \\
    d 
  \end{pmatrix}$ be two vectors in the plane. Do we have the existence of an inner product that makes $X,Y$ an orthonormal basis?

I think of finding a positive definite matrix $A$ such as $X^TAX=1$ and $X^TAY=0$. Is this the right direction? Does it also work for vectors of higher dimension?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are linearly dependent you cannot do this. Otherwise you can define $\langle (aX+bY, cX+dY \rangle =ac+bd$.

Answer (score 0):

Just define$$(\forall\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathbb R):\left\langle\alpha X+\beta Y,\gamma X+\delta Y\right\rangle=\alpha\gamma+\beta\delta.$$